# Почему socket() возвращает -1?

Tags: c++, сокет, winsock

Пытаюсь создать сокет на windows таким образом:

```
SOCKET sock;
if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    cout << "socket() error: " << errno << "\n";
```

Входит в тело условия. Вывод:

> socket() error:  34

Код именно такой, потому что хотел сохранить совместимость с Linux. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело

Comment: `strerror(errno)` подскажет в чём дело...

Comment: @Fat-Zer пишет "Result too large", не понятно. Может необходима инициализация контекста WSA?

Comment: мда, не особо оно подсказывает... действительно похоже на отсутствие какой-то специфической инициализации... и кстати, хотя реализации BSD-сокетов и похожие из-за мелких отличий в 9 случаях из 10 под win приходится писать отдельную реализацию...

Comment: @Fat-Zer после инициализации заработало

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) написано что в случае ошибки функция вернет `INVALID_SOCKET` (-1) и код ошибки можно получить вызовом функции `WSAGetLastError`.
`errno` при этом не выставляется т.к. `socket` это системная функция и она ничего не знает про `errno`.

И скорее всего там ошибка `WSANOTINITIALISED` - не вызвана функция `WSAStartup`.